# Forbidden Island - Extending to 5 players

Tags: forbidden-island

I'm having friends over this weekend and we are going to play Forbidden Island, we are 5 all in all and was wondering if we can play Forbidden Island with 5 players. Are there any adjustments to be made? Will the additional player make the game too easy or all in all break the game?

Thanks!

Comment: It will make it probably slightly harder. You now have more players that will have to move to other players locations to get 4 of the 5 treasures of each color. The difficulty increase is probably insignificant compared to he difference in playing at Legenday versus Standard difficulty, or playing some of the more elaborate island configurations.

Comment: Forbidden Island [official variant maps](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/569926/official-variant-tile-layouts)

Comment: Check the related [question](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1971/does-forbidden-island-usually-need-any-rule-variants-for-playing-with-5-people) for more information

Answer (score 1):

I tried: you can, but each difficulty level is to be considered one lower.

In order to be able to have a chance to win with your friend if they have never played the game and that you want to start easy, you have to put the water cursor below the first line, adding a new level of difficulty: "extra-novice".

But if you intend to have more than 4 players regularly, may I suggest you buy another cooperative game that is suitable for 5?

- [**Atlantis Rising**](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/92120/atlantis-rising) (2-6 players) takes some of the same principle of drowning land, without being exacly the same game.
- [**Battlestar Galactica**](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/37111/battlestar-galactica) (3-6 players) is a team vs team game, except you don't know in which team you are until the middle of the game.
- [**Shadows over Camelot**](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/15062/shadows-over-camelot) (3-7 players) allows each player to follow his own quest, but be sure to find the traitor and don't let him ruin your work!
- [**Hanabi**](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/98778/hanabi) (2-5 players) asks every player to launch fireworks by playing cards in the right order (exactly like [Ligretto](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/943/ligretto)) except you hold your cards backwards and everybody sees them except you.
- There are [**3319 co-operative games**](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamemechanic/2023/co-operative-play) (when I write this answer) listed on Board Game Geek!